# I wished somebody told me

Tags: past-tense, would

I got to the bank this morning to open an account, but I could not because I did not have one of the documents required. The day before, when I booked the appointment with the advisor, they told me to bring this and that with me, but they did not mention that extra document.

I was very pissed off, and I told the advisor:

1) "I wished somebody would have told me I needed..."

Is that good English? Is this one maybe better?

2) "I wished somebody told me I needed ...."

or

3) "I wish somebody told me I needed ..."

1), 2) or 3) or maybe a new one?

Comment: "You should have told me......"

Comment: @Josh61 - I booked the appointment with somebody else, not with him. Or maybe you mean "you" as in "your organisation". Right?

Comment: They didnt inform you about all the documents you were  supposed  to take with you, so "someone should have told you"  what documents you needed. Do you want to use the expression "I wish" in this case?

Comment: @Josh61 - yes, I think the point is that I want to use "I wish".

Comment: What about "I wish somebody had told me"? Just suggesting..

Comment: _I wish somebody had told me_. The use of the past perfect is appropriate for an event (the omission of a key fact in the conversation) prior to a past event (your visit to the bank). In other words, the conversation you had with the advisor was anterior (prior) to your visit to the bank, and the past perfect is employed to convey that temporal location.